# Opera browser not working in Japan

Tags: laptop, opera

I'm temporarily near Osaka in the South of Japan. Previously I was in South Korea and everything was fine, but now I'm experiencing a problem here in Japan.

I'm using a Windows 8 Acer laptop, and connecting to the Internet over a standard wifi connection. Normally I use the Opera browser but all the standard websites I have tried to go to (like Google/Yahoo) seem to be blocked... apart from www.dnsleaktest.com, which shows that my ISP is in Amagasaki.

Firefox and Chrome work perfectly, but not Opera. That's a problem for me because all of my bookmarks are in Opera. It seems very odd to me that dnsleaktest should work in Opera, but not Google.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening, and a possible solution?

Thanks a lot. Arigatou!

Answer (score 0):

Opera **can** use a mode called Opera Turbo.

In that mode the browser doesn't make the request directly to the website (*Google, Yahoo, etc.*) but through Opera servers.

[image]

The Opera servers make the request and compress the data sent to you, giving you the feeling of a faster speed compared to the direct request.

Besides of that they offer a Free VPN integrated with the browser.

[image]

Check which one you have enabled (they are mutually exclusive) and disable it. It's very likely that one of them is causing the problem.